# log deleted files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am using the following command to delete the files that are older than 10 days, but I also want to store(log) the list of files that are being deleted using the below command.

```
find ./path/delete -type f -name '*' -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: soo `... rm -v {} \;` ?

Comment: Cross-site dupes: [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651315/how-do-you-output-the-filename-in-find-command-while-using-exec), [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66505/how-to-print-find-match-as-well-as-run-an-exec). TL;DR: add `-print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a file to log to (`touch ./path/to/logfile`), just add another `-exec` to your command. Below is a very basic example, but you can add to it:

```
find ./path/delete -type f -name '*' -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \; -exec echo {} >> ./path/to/logfile \;
```